# How to read an email's message body using the *imap.Message (emersion/go-imap)

Tags: go, imap

After finding the correct email out of a handful of the most recent ones I try to read the message body but nothing gets printed. I've tried every example I could find online and none of them really show how to read the message body using just the *imap.Message object

Most of the code was taken from emersion's example on github but I've slightly modified somethings to fit my usecase.

```golang
func getEmail(){
    log.Println("Connecting to server...")

    // Connect to server
    c, err := client.DialTLS("imap.gmail.com" + ":993", nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Connected")

    // Don't forget to logout
    defer c.Logout()

    // Login
    if err := c.Login(ImapUser, ImapPass); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("Logged in")

    // List mailboxes
    mailboxes := make(chan *imap.MailboxInfo, 10)
    done := make(chan error, 1)
    go func () {
        done <- c.List("", "*", mailboxes)
    }()

    for m := range mailboxes {
        _ = m
    }

    if err := <-done; err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Select INBOX
    mbox, err := c.Select("INBOX", false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // Get the last 4 messages
    from := uint32(1)

    to := mbox.Messages

    if mbox.Messages > 3 {
        // We're using unsigned integers here, only subtract if the result is > 0
        from = mbox.Messages - 3
    }
    seqset := new(imap.SeqSet)
    seqset.AddRange(from, to)

    messages := make(chan *imap.Message, 10)
    done = make(chan error, 1)

    go func() {
        done <- c.Fetch(seqset, []imap.FetchItem{imap.FetchEnvelope}, messages)
    }()

    for msg := range messages {
        if strings.Contains(fmt.Sprint(msg.Envelope.To[0]), strings.ToLower(Credentials.email)){
            log.Println("> Got Email")

            log.Println(msg.Body)   
        }
    }

    if err := <-done; err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you must wait for c.Fetch inside goroutine

Answer (score 1):

Check first if [`emersion/go-imap` issue 306](https://github.com/emersion/go-imap/issues/306) would apply:

> To get raw message, you should use `Fetch` with "`BODY.PEEK[]`" fetch item. This will give you an `io.Reader` with the complete message contents as presented by server.
>
> Something like that:

```golang
ch := make(chan *imap.Message, 1)
err := c.Fetch(yourSeqset, []imap.FetchItem{imap.FetchItem("BODY.PEEK[]")}, ch)
if err != nil {
  ...
}
msg := <-ch
for name, literal := range msg.Body {
  // literal is the io.Reader you want
}
```